# UICollectionView cell selection issue - only cells on the visible area when view is loaded can not be selected

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, selection, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to use UICollectionView to develop a day calendar for my app.

[ScreenShot of my day calendar.The view contain 00:00 to 24:00 is developed by collection view. In the bottom is a tableview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wfwM.png)

I used customized UICollectioViewLayout to display every cells and it works fine!! Every cell is showed in right position.

In order to show more information of each events, I implement [didSelectItemAtIndexPath] method coupled with [prepareForSegue] method to trigger a popover view to show data when user touch a cell.

However, only cells that do no show in the visible area when collectionview is first time loaded can be selected.

I mean that the contentsize of collectionview is [1560,340] and the frame size of collectionview is [560, 340]. So this collection view can scroll vertically. I found that if the position of a cell is higher than [560, 340](eg. [30,340]), this cells can not be selected. If the position of cells are lower than [560, 340], user touched these cells can trigger didSelectItemAtIndexPath method and show a popoverview.

I totally have no idea about what is going wrong. Is anyone ever encounter similar issue?

Comment: If you scroll down, then scroll up again, can you still select the first items ?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem may come from zIndex.

In my original design. The timeLabels and the two vertical lines, which is the borderLine of a UILabel, were displayed by SupplementaryView. The events were displayed by UICollectionViewCell. I found that if I remove the SupplementaryView, all cells can be selected correctly. So I next tried to display everything (events, lines, time) by UICollectionViewCell. However, the selection issue is still happen. Finally, I found that there is a parameter called zIndex. After I setting the zIndex of cells that display event to 1 and others cells to 0, the selection issue is gone. Everything works perfectly.

Although I do no try, I think that, in my original design, if I set the zIndex of SupplementaryView to 0 may solve the selection issue.